# Creating Data-Processing Machines with Screens: Can Arduino or Raspberry Pi Do It?

Tags: robotics

guys! I'm a web developer, and I want to create some small machines that have a screen at the front. This machines will accept data, process it via an HTTP request, and display the results using a projector at the back. I'm wondering if I can achieve this with Arduino or Raspberry Pi. Can this type of machine be created using these two hardware options? I'm a Python developer.

Comment: So, how much data processing is needed? You should be able to work that out based on the data, requests and results. Given that you can check the processing capability of your chosen processor, or select a processor based on those computing needs...

Comment: What do you mean by "process it via an http request?"  Do you mean it'll send the data off to the cloud and get an answer?  Or are you somehow constraining yourself to have an internal API that's tied to http?

Comment: Yes, I meant that: `Do you mean it'll send the data off to the cloud and get an answer? `

Comment: Sorry -- you're a newbie.  Please _edit your question_ for completeness.  The two things that are unclear _in the question itself_ are this point (the data is processed remotely) and how complex you want the screen to be (because I may have been a bit too down on the Arduino in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Arduino: Well, anything is possible.  How many hours do you have to wait between clicking "OK" and getting a new screen?

Raspberry Pi: If you're not doing too much processing, yes.  It's basically a little, cheap, underpowered laptop.  As long as you're familiar with Linux, developing on it will look very familiar indeed.

Comment: +1 lots of arduino compatible microcontrollers around that could do this no problem. Raspberry pi can be unobtainium. Though why the hell not take a android phone and kioskify it or even a laptop.

Comment: @joojaa: microcontroller chips?  Since the OP describes themself as "a Python programmer" I'm assuming that they need something that can be stuck together and only needs some Python to connect the dots.

Comment: so there are arduino variants that have builtin wifi and no problem talking over http. Stick a segment display and your set. Also there is the micro python that you can run on stuff like RP2040 microcontrollers. But yeah a raspberry is easy, as is any other device in category like a beaglebone. But raspberry PI's are sometimes hard to get due to insufficient manufacturing.